# Let A, B, C be sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $(A − C) \cap (C − B) = \varnothing$. Homework question that I've been stuck on for a bit. I'm supposed to prove it by contradiction.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I let x be an element of (A - C) ∩ (C - B), which would mean x∈A-C and X∈C-B but not really sure what where to go from there.

Comment: It's literally the first result when you google ''(A − C) ∩ (C − B) = ∅". [(link)](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~amiller/2513-su05/ClassProblems/Solution6-15.pdf). Did you not think looking up the problem would be quicker than waiting for us to write an answer?

Comment: I did google it and I just got similar questions not this one, if you got a link would be nice if you can send it my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to contrary that $(A-C)\cap(C-B) \ne \emptyset$

Then there exist $x\in (A-C)\cap(C-B)$, so $x\in (A-C)$ and $x\in (C-B)$ this means that $x\in A$ and $x\not\in C$ and $x\in C$ and $x\not\in B$, thus a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. $A-C = A\cap C^c$.   $\ $